# How to prevent crash from java.util.Date.toString?

Tags: java, android

Occasionally, the following code causes an Android app crash:

```
try {
    (new Date()).toString());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ...
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl$ZNames.getNameTypeIndex (TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:724)
  at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl$ZNames.getName (TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:790)
  at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl.getTimeZoneDisplayName (TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:183)
  at android.icu.text.TimeZoneNames.getDisplayName (TimeZoneNames.java:261)
  at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName (TimeZone.java:405)
  at java.util.Date.toString (Date.java:1066)
```

Apparently, the error cannot be caught.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you specify which version of android do you target?

Comment: To debug, you might try storing `new Date()` in a variable and accessing various fields.

Comment: `AssertionError` extends `Error` not `Exception`. You can catch it if you explicitly catch `AssertionError`

Comment: related https://github.com/google/volley/issues/177

Comment: @crgarridos targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird issue...

BTW there is not exception thrown, but an `AssertionError` who extends from `Error`.

You can catch it using:

```
try {
    (new Date()).toString());
} catch (AssertionError ex) {// or Error or Throwable
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the AssertionError using **new Date()** which seems strange and possibly related to an **Android 8** issue as opposed to your code, you can use **java.time** from **Java 8** instead of **java.util.Date** like so:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()); //you must add time zone because of Instant

Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.now();

System.out.print(formatter.format(currentTimestamp));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Yes, it happens only with Android 8.1 devices.  I assume your answer will work, but unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers.

Comment: @Hong I believe you can change which you accept, should you care to.

Comment: I know that I can change the answer, but I cannot accept two answers simultaneously if I understand it correctly.  I assume the first answer also works in preventing the crash.

Comment: Right direction in this Answer using *java.time*, but `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, **`LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment**. Instead, use `Instant` for UTC or `ZonedDateTime` for a particular time zone.

Comment: @Basil Bourque okay cool thanks for the note! I'm guessing you were the down vote, which is fine although I would have improved my answer just from your comment, but I have made an update to my post using **Instant** so I'm not sure why the down vote stands, if it was you. Either way, every snippet I provided does offer a working alternative solution to the OPs original issue.

Comment: @ViaTech My down-vote remains because this Answer continues to recommend the wrong class. You needn’t take my word for it. Simply read [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html): *cannot represent an instant on the timeline*. I would also down-vote an Answer that somehow managed to sum `( 2 + 2 )` using Strings or a bit array rather than using `int`, `Integer`, or `BigInteger`. An apparently-correct result does not justify abusing the wrong classes inappropriately.

Comment: @Basil Bourque okay solid link. I have removed my examples that use **LocalDateTime**. However, technically based on the OPs question there is no notation of what the date is for, and the documentation you presented does say it is acceptable for Birthdays, who knows maybe that would have helped someone